Black Scholes Stochastic Calc P&L
I am reading The Volatility Smile by Emanuel Derman and Michael Miller, and am struggling with the technical details behind the following SDE for the P&L of a continuously delta-hedged long position in a European Call option under Black Scholes.
Roughly quoting the text, the P&L is modeled as follows:

The value of the delta hedged portfolio at any time t, is given by:
${\Pi_t = C_t - \Delta_{BSM}*S_t}$.
Where ${C_t}$ is the market price of the call option (evolves using Implied Volatility >${\sigma_I}$), while ${S_t}$ and ${\Delta_t}$ are computed using the Geometric Brownian Motion assuming realized volatility ${\sigma_R \neq\sigma_I}$. Hence, the incremental P&L at any time t is given >by:
$${d(P\&L) = d(C_t)-d(\Delta_{BSM} S_t)}$$
$${=dC_t-\Delta_{BSM}dS_t-(C_t-\Delta_{BSM}S_t)rdt}$$
Where ${dC_t}$ is the incremental change in the value of the call option, ${\Delta_{BSM}dS_t}$ is the incremental change in the short position in the stock, and ${(C_t-\Delta_{BSM}S_t)rdt}$ is the incremental cost of borrowing to purchase the call position net of the cash earned by shorting position the stock.

From this, it seems that the implication is ${d(\Delta_{BSM}S_t) = \Delta_{BSM}dS_t + (C_t-\Delta_{BSM}S_t)rdt}$? How could this be derived from stochastic calculus? Is the incremental P&L possibly something other than ${d\Pi_t}$?
I've tried using Ito Calculus to say ${d(\Delta_{BSM}S_t) = d(\Delta_{BSM})S_t + \Delta_{BSM}dS_t + d(\Delta_{BSM})d(S_t)}$, and applying Ito's lemma to ${d\Delta_{BSM}}$, but I cannot get to the final P&L result provided by the text. And the text does not provide the steps, it only says it's obvious.

Going purely by your quote, I think the justification for this equation is financial, not mathematical, and is given in the sentence directly after the equation.

It would be helpful if you linked the exact copy of the text you’re referring to so we have more context. My version doesn’t have that quote anywhere. But from what you have given us, I’m guessing it’s the PnL gained (lost) from delta hedging when you’re long (short) options if the realised volatility is greater than the implied volatility (cost of option). You gain money perfectly delta hedging an option you own if the realised volatility is greater than the implied volatility

What the authors do here (@Wei got it) is to tell us that the hedging strategy is self-financing. How this relates to Ito calculus, most notably to the integration-by-parts formula, is discussed in this MSE post.

You can check out "Options, Futures, and Other Derivatives
" by John C hull

The correct PnL is in integral form
$\int_0^T \Delta_tdS_t$
and not $\int_0^T d \left ( \Delta_t S_t \right ) = \Delta_T S_T - \Delta_0 S_0$
The strategy has to be self-financing.
Do it in discrete time and you will see the difference. You buy $N_t$ shares, and gain $N_t (S_{t+1}-S_t)$, then you rebalance to $N_{t+1}$ and do the same.
You will have to compute the increments day by day (and so the integral), the PnL of your portfolio is not only, $N_T S_T$, you will have to subtract the cost you paid to buy the $N_T$ shares.
This is the definition of self financing. Everything else would not make sense.
See as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-financing_portfolio#Continuous_time
